# UIDocument not saving

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument

I'm trying to implement a `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` (new in iOS 11). I can create documents but I can't save them.

My `UIDocument` subclass overrrides the `contents(forType typeName: String)` method

```
override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
    guard let data = content.data(using: .ascii) else { return Data() }
    return data
}
```

My file editing ViewController gets instantiated with the document and a button press should save the document.

```
@IBAction func dismissDocumentViewController() {

    document?.content = self.contentTextView.text

    let url = self.document?.fileURL

    self.document?.save(to: url!, for: .forOverwriting, completionHandler: { (success) in
        print("Saved \(success)")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Calling save does not save the document and I also tried as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571511/4089350

```
self.document?.close(completionHandler: { (success) in
    print("closed \(success)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

It prints that it closed the document but it isn't actually saved.

How do I save a UIDocument correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you called updateChangeCount() so it knows there are changes in need of saving?

Comment: Prove that `self.document` is not `nil`. Conversely, prove that the document is "not saved". — Also I would point out that your way of "saving" a document (in your `contents(forType:)` implementation) is not very robust. Have you tried putting a breakpoint to see what `data` is?